# Dynamic routing with "routerLink" return undefined Angular 10

Tags: angular, routes, router, angular-routerlink, dynamic-routing

I used the following routing to return the detailPage of each product `<a [routerLink]="['/shop-left-two/', tempProduct?.id]">`

I got this error
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()**

and my localhost@ **http://localhost:4200/shop-left-two/undefined**

**ps** : when I enter **http://localhost:4200/shop-left-two/1** it works fine and returns the productDetails  of the productid=1

**shoplefttwo.component.html**

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" *ngFor="let tempProduct of products ">
  <div class="food-box shop-box style-2">
    <div class="thumb">
      <a [routerLink]="['/shop-left-two/', tempProduct?.id]">
        <img src="{{tempProduct.imageUrl}}" alt="images"> 
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**shopdetail.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Product } from 'src/app/common/product';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/services/product.service';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-shopdetail',
  templateUrl: './shopdetail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shopdetail.component.css']
})
export class ShopdetailComponent implements OnInit {
  
  product:Product= new Product();
  constructor(private productService: ProductService ,
              private route:ActivatedRoute      ) { }
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe( () =>{
      this.handleProductDetails();
    })
  }
  handleProductDetails() {
  const theProductId:number = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  this.productService.getProduct(theProductId).subscribe(
    data =>{
      this.product= data ;
    }
  )
  }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
  {path :'shop-left-two/:id' ,component:ShopdetailComponent ,data: { breadcrumb: 'Shop Detail' }}
```

Comment: What values does `products` have when running the loop?

Comment: @HarunYilmaz  products is an array that works fine and it shows all the products of the database

Answer (score 0):

The `id` for `tempProduct` is the issue, since you are using the save navigation operator (?), appends `undefined`

Now the question is, why `id` is `undefined`? Even though sounds like is a temporary product based on the name `tempProduct`, it should have an id...

If you are getting that `undefined` value, then skip it

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" *ngFor="let tempProduct of products ">
  <div 
    class="food-box shop-box style-2" 
    *ngIf="temProduct?.id"> // show only if tempProduct has ID in it
    <div class="thumb">
      <a [routerLink]="['/shop-left-two/', tempProduct.id]">
        <img src="{{tempProduct.imageUrl}}" alt="images"> 
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

I see you have a property called `product`, and in the template HTML you have `products`... maybe that's the problem? Also, your `product` should be an `array`

```js
export class ShopdetailComponent implements OnInit {
  products: Product[]= []//new Product();
  ...
  ...
  ...
  

  this.productService.getProduct(theProductId).subscribe(
    data => this.products = data
  )
```

Comment: For The first one it didn't work and it still returns undefined and I can't set it to id=1 since I have other products with different Id  and for the property product it's declared in another service called product.ts  `export class Product {
    id:string;
    sku:  string;
    name :string;
    description:string;
    unitPrice:number;
    imageUrl:string;
    active:boolean;
    unitsInStock:number;
    dateCreated:Date;
    lastUpdated:Date;

}
`

Comment: and in the ts of the component shop-left-two I 've set it like this `products: Product[]=[];`

Comment: @HoudaBoukhobza Did you try console.log the response from this.productService.getProduct(theProductId) ? Can you post that data here?

Comment: of course i got this in the console  `ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: 'OK', url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/products/NaN', ok: false, …}`

Comment: That's the issue then, you are getting 500 from the backend, not the actual data

Comment: how to fix this Error please?